# click the ion-back-button will change the query parameters in the address bar

Tags: angular, ionic4

example:pageA url is `localhost:8100/address?from=1`,then pageA navigate to pageB `localhost:8100/edit`,then the pageB click `ion-back-button` back to pageA,but pageA url will be become is `localhost:8100/address`,the url query param `?from=1` is none,why is that?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The [defaltHref](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/back-button#properties) is used when your navigation history is empty, as a fallback.